# Count the phrases in a pdf file and display the phrases with the count for each phrase

Tags: java, count, pdfbox

Input: pdf file with a set of defined words (phrases)

Required Output: I need to display the phrases and their count in the whole pdf

My code below is always giving me count = 1. I believe that is happening because it is not checking the entire file.

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.Loader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class task {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File("filepath));
            PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String pdfText = textStripper.getText(document);
            String[] sentencesToSearch = {
                    "hotels, restaurants, airlines, golf clubs, food and beverage, meeting, theme park, cruise, casino",
                    "revenue management techniques",
                    "Excel",
                    "data",
                    "marketing",
                    "finance",
                    "cost",
                    "economic principles",
                    "strategy",
                    "knowledge of",
                    "that"
            };
            Map<String, Integer> sentenceCount = new HashMap<>();

            for (String sentence : sentencesToSearch) {
                    if (pdfText.contains(sentence)) {
                        sentenceCount.put(sentence, sentenceCount.getOrDefault(sentence, 0) + 1);
                    }
            }
            document.close();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sentenceCount.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Sentence: " + entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("Count: " + entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that worked using Regex:

```
for (String word : definedWords) {                 
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b");                 
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pdfText);                  
   int count = 0;                 
   while (matcher.find()) {                     
      count++;                 
   }                 
   phraseCount.put(word, count);             
}
```

Comment: Please read through your code again, and explain how you could ever get a count greater than 1.

Comment: I did using the regax and it works fine but I want to use latest way of writting it.

Here my code using regax : 
`for (String word : definedWords) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pdfText);

                int count = 0;
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    count++;
                }
                phraseCount.put(word, count);
            }`

@tgdavies

Comment: What is the "latest way of writing it"?

Comment: You're testing once for each sentence. You're not checking the position and then looking for more "hits" after the position + length of word. So yes, it will be 1 max in the original code.

Comment: If your "latest way of writing it" is the code in your question, then (as other comments already say) you only check whether the test phrase appears in the content (`1`) or not (`0`). In that case please tell why you want to use this latest way instead of the regular expression variant.